# U-statistics with infinite moment

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be i.i.d. in a probability space $(\Omega,\mu)$, $F(X,Y)$ a non-negative measurable function on $(\Omega\times \Omega,\mu\times \mu)$ such that $\mathbb{E}\, F(X,Y)=\infty$. What is known about the possible limit distribution laws for $\sum_{1\leqslant i<j\leqslant n} F(X_i,X_j)$, after appropriate normalization? Both the cases with heavy $\approx t^{-c}$ and more heavy tails of the distribution of $F(X,Y)$ are of interest.

Comment: I mean that $X_i$ are points of $\Omega$, not random variables. But this seems to be equivalent. I also expect $\alpha$-stable distributions, but I do not want to reinvent the bicycle. This has to be studied, there are tons of papers on U-statistics.

Comment: They are distributed in $\Omega$ independently according to the probability measure in $\Omega$. In other words, yes, $(X_1,X_2,\ldots)\in \Omega^{\mathbb{N}}$ with respect to the product measure.

Comment: Did you see [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167715222002279)?

Comment: Also, [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.11563)? Any other papers on this that you have seen?

Comment: @IosifPinelis thank you for the references! I have just had a look, and both papers unfortunately seem to start with the finite first moment assumption. So do all other papers on the subject which I did see. Possibly, because in statistics these guys are used for estimating this unknown first moment?

Comment: @FedorPetrov : I think the first moment condition is needed to use Hoeffding's original idea involving $EF(X_1,x)$ for $x\in\Omega$. So, one might need a whole new paradigm without the first moment condition. Maybe, some truncation can help?